# How to use OAuth 2.0 Google+ Signup with iOS App/Server to make user accounts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, google-plus

I'm making an iOS app—I want it to have Google+ Signup/Login. I have a server that works all fine with normal accounts. It works where you send up a username and password and it gives a token which is what is saved on the device—and used for making any requests from the app.

For Google+ Signup, I want it to work where they can signup, we get information from them like profile image, name, email, etc. We use that information to make them an account on our database. I then want them to be able to click login with google and it will sign them in.

What is the best way to achieve this, if possible? Any recommendations? Using Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer,But i would like to say that my app was rejected from appstore last time saying Google+ oAuth login is going out of app for authentication.You can search and see that this is a common issue.

This was the message i got from appstore :***"We found the following issues with the user interface of your app: The app opens a web page in mobile Safari for creating an account or logging in, then returns the user to the app. The user should be able to create an account or log in without opening Safari first."***

Google+ login will open safari for login,which is not supported by apple.I removed the google+ login and then my my app was accepted by appstore.

Do a research about this issue.Best of luck,dont waste time.

see [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/37) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=900)..you can find more in stackoverflow